# jQuery / Js — Accessing Variables in a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I'm trying to streamline my code a little by setting up functions rather than repeating the same lines of code over again:

```
function pledgeSpanish() {
    $(name).attr('placeholder', 'Tu nombre... *');
    $(email).attr('placeholder', 'Tu correo electrónico... *');
    $(nationality).text('Nacionalidad....');
    $(radioPublic).text('Soy miembro del compromiso global de apoyo a las comunidades afectadas por las mineras.');
    $(radioCommunity).text('Provengo o trabajo en una comunidad afectada por las mineras. Me gustaría contactar con otros miembros del movimiento “Si a la Vida, No a la Minera” y recibir las últimas actualizaciones.');
    $(buttonSubmit).val('Firma La Petición');
}
```

But when I try to run the script, I get the error

> email is not defined

Funnily enough, I don't get an error for the 'name' field

How would I go about modifying it so that I can access the variables from within the function?

Comment: Where are you defining `email` ?

Comment: Do you have global variables somewhere? If not, than you will get that error every time.

Comment: ahhh do I need to define them before the function with the `var` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Amended like so:

```
var name           = $('#form-pledge .field-name input');
var email          = $('#form-pledge .field-email input');
var nationality    = $('#form-pledge .field-nationality select option:first');
var radioPublic    = $('#form-pledge .gfield_radio li:first label');
var radioCommunity = $('#form-pledge .gfield_radio li:last label');
var buttonSubmit   = $('#form-pledge input[type="submit"]');

function pledgeSpanish() {
    $(name).attr('placeholder', 'Tu nombre... *');
    $(email).attr('placeholder', 'Tu correo electrónico... *');
    $(nationality).text('Nacionalidad....');
    $(radioPublic).text('Soy miembro del compromiso global de apoyo a las comunidades afectadas por las mineras.');
    $(radioCommunity).text('Provengo o trabajo en una comunidad afectada por las mineras. Me gustaría contactar con otros miembros del movimiento “Si a la Vida, No a la Minera” y recibir las últimas actualizaciones.');
    $(buttonSubmit).val('Firma La Petición');
}
```

Is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: With `var name = $( ... )` your variables are jQuery-objects. So inside your function you don't need `$( ...)` again, referencing by name is enough: `name.attr( ... );` ... .